# AWS Lambda upload to S3 time out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm fairly new to AWS Lambda and I'm facing a problem. I'm developing in Node and I'm downloading JSON file (quite big ones 12-25MB) from my S3, doing some processing and trying to upload the result in form of JSON back to S3.

I was following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html which does essentially the same thing.

My problem is that my lambda always times out when calling `JSON.stringify` on an object that I get as a result of my data processing and thus the file never gets uploaded back to S3. The result of my processing is also a quite big object but still smaller as the input (cca. 10MB).
I already tried to use `fast-json-stringify` library but I ended up with the same result.

Does anyone know if there is any other faster way to convert an object to string, buffer or stream?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code:

```
async.waterfall(
  [
    (next) => {
      s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: keyDownload
      }, next);
    },
    (response, next) => {
      next(null, processData(JSON.parse(response.Body)));
    },
    (data, next) => {
      s3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: keyUpload,
        Body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }, next);
    }
  ], 
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is on `JSON.stringify`? Does your AWS Lambda got `putObject` permissions on the bucket to write the file?

Comment: Yes. My lambda has `putObject` permission. I'm sure that the problem is in `JSON.stringify` because if I remove it and put some dummy text as `Body` of the file, the file actually gets created on S3.

Comment: Have you tried improving your Lambda's performance by increasing the memory? By increasing the memory you also get your code to run in better CPUs. Since JSON.stringify is an IO intensive task, increasing the memory could help.

Comment: Yes. I increased the memory to maximum and it did not help.

Comment: Are you throwing an error and not catching on the `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: No. There is no error being thrown when calling `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share your code. Have you tried with small set of files to being with to confirm your function is working as expected?

Comment: I will share my code when I get home. Yes, I have tried it with a small object and it works fine.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Make sure you don't have cycles in the JSON object, and take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json

Answer (score 0):

Did you try S3 multi-part upload, I would suggest that's a place to look into -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

Comment: Thank you. I will try this when I get home.

Comment: MPU is a rabbit hole and most likely not your problem. You only need to multi part when you have a file more that 100MB, so you are well within your limit

Comment: Yeah @LostJon, you're right. I didn't take in the size of file in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

- Just a random thought after looking at the example you are following.
- if you are using the aws cli to create the lambda function just
  wondering what is the **--timeout** value that you have given. The example says `--timeout 10` which is 10 sec which is definitely small time span.
- You can check/change it on the aws console as well and try and increase it to say 10 min i.e. 600 sec (this is just for testing if this is the problem or not later on you can get down to some appropriate value after evaluation).
- The timeout is optional value while creating via aws cli. Thus the default is 3 seconds. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds i.e 15 min.
- Definitely multi-part upload will be helpful.

Comment: I tried different time out values. Up to 5 minutes and it does not seem to help. I will take a look at multi-part upload but the problem occurs even before upload. The problem is when I execute `const data = JSON.stringify(output)`